# Unable to start debugging because the object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I'm running Visual Studio 2012 (version 11.0.61030.00 update 4). When debugging a local console application I get the following error when I start debugging (F5):

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Error while trying to run project: Unable to start debugging.
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

This only happens if I leave visual studio alone without debugging for a couple minutes. If I close visual studio and re-open the error goes away (until I leave it untouched for another couple of minutes). Has anyone experienced this? I can't find any threads of other people experiencing it.

Comment: Simply close and restart VS. That's the only solution worked for me for sometime. After getting update it disappeared.

Comment: This may or may not be related: are you running Microsoft BitLocker?

Comment: I get the same problem with VS2010 and VS2013, so it doesn't seem specific to VS2012.

Comment: Same VS2013 Ultimate, Update 2 -- Console app util.

Comment: [This MSDN question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/be30c158-154e-4a89-84b8-019e875b5725/vs-2010-beta-2-the-operation-could-not-be-completed-occurs-with-debug-and-release-chosen?forum=vsdebug) seems to have solved a issue similar to this by renaming a folder called VS7DEBUG in `%PROGRAM_FILES%/Common Files\Microsoft Shared`. Did you try that?

Comment: Try to run without debugging (Ctrl + F5). If you are not getting any error then problem could be Visual Studio debugger msdbg2.dll might not be installed correctly. Try to repair Visual Studio, If the problem persists then manually register msdbg2.dll from command prompt. Also check if following folder exist "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\" and if the problem persists then try to rename folder "VS7Debug".

Comment: Just to add evidence. This happened to me on VS 2005 after I shutdown windows while VS was building. After restarting the machine this started happening. Restarting VS solved it.

Comment: Can also happen w/VS 2017  - although I have never ever seen this before after using this edition for months.. but.. here I am googling...

Comment: I have the same issue, but only when debugging with IE (I never receive the error with Chrome). Exact error I'm getting in VS2015 is: "Unable to start program 'https://localhost:44300/'. The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.".  As others have pointed out, Restarting VS, works, but only temporarily.

Comment: This all started for me after work forced me to install Antivirus software called Cloudstrike Falcon (WindowsSensor.exe).  Who knows what its interfering with. RESTARTING VISUAL STUDIO IS NOT A SOLUTION. That's the PROBLEM. This is happening in Visual Studio 2017 (latest as of commenting), but a web search reveals that this error occurs outside of visual studio, even on the windows login screen, so it's a bigger issue.

Answer (score 36):

[This may be a possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835026/visual-studio-freezes-when-switching-to-debug-mode/1838147#1838147) for the problem.

Some from the answer:

1. Check which files were changed (why and how) after update from a source control engine
2. Review the list of extensions and plugins. Try to disable all or some of them
3. Close Visual Studio and kill all the development processes: `devenv, mspdbsrv, vcpkgsrv, msbuild, msvsmon, vshub, vstest` etc
4. Remove `.suo, .ncb, .VC.db, .VC.VC.opendb` files of the solution as well as `.vs` directory, which sometimes cause problems
5. Remove project setting files, sort of `YourProjectName.vcproj.DOMAINNAME.LOGINNAME.user` or `YourProjectName.csproj.user`. The setting file name depends on a project kind you use
6. Run `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /setup` or `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /setup` for x64 environment

Comment: @RezaS _Restarting Visual Studio_ is just a temporary solution and just like what's the in the question (_This only happens if I leave visual studio alone without debugging for a couple minutes. If I close visual studio and re-open the error goes away (until I leave it untouched for another couple of minutes)_), It will keep bugging you again.

Comment: Step 4 worked for me. You should also try doing the other steps in this answer.

Comment: I had two instances of visual studio opened, one with a project which is integrating with a peripheral device and the other was throwing this error. I had to close both instances and starting this one again to make it work

Comment: A repair of the installation is the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: I had to remove the hidden .vs folder at the root of my project. (This folder just holds user settings and will be recreated when the project is reloaded.)

Comment: In step 4, did you mean the `.vs` directory, not the `.vc` directory?

Answer (score 11):

**Just Close the VIsual Studio and start again the project.Its work Perfectly for me.**
Thanks

Comment: That's not a great solution when it happens 20 times a day

Comment: @codinglifestyle  this problem is just a temporary problem and restarting visual studio will solve the problem.

Comment: It's a temporary solution, not a temporary problem.

Comment: October 2017, VS Enterprise 2017. It's still happening. This is most assuredly not a temporary problem. I'm with @Fábio.

Comment: I understand both sides of the coin. In my case, it was indeed temporary. Not really sure, but, it seems to have occurred after I went tinkering with my build configuration (added a new build config to all projects in my .sln, then selectively reverted it out of certain .csproj files). Restart worked.

Comment: So, What actually is the permanent solution for this problem guys? Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: This is something like peoples are getting benifit from this answer and doing downvotes.Please do answer if you have any permanent solution instead of downvote this.

Answer (score 3):

While restarting Visual Studio does provide a workaround, it doesn't solve the actual problem.  In my case, I was working with a C# solution in VS2017 and the following resolved the issue:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete the .vs folder that was created in the Solution's directory
3. Re-open the Solution

Comment: Do note of course that this will result in loss of history information like the record of what files you last had opened when you re-open the Solution.

Answer (score 0):

I corrupted my App.config file with NLog settings without section Handler in the top of the document. Gist is check out your config file settings either corrupted in format or not properly handled any section. once I remove corrupted config section, it did not raise the error again (VS 2017)
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have just reinstalled `Windows 10` and so the `Visual Studio 2022`..

My project was targeting `.net 5 SDK`, but I only had `.net 6 SDK` installed. The solution was to install earlier version of the `SDK`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic error something has gone wrong and could be anything. It's worth having a look through event viewer's recent errors.

In my case I could see errors logged with a `.NET Runtime` source, something like this:

```
Description: A .NET application failed.
Application: ServiceHub.RoslynCodeAnalysisService.exe
Path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\ServiceHub\Hosts\ServiceHub.Host.Dotnet.x64\ServiceHub.RoslynCodeAnalysisService.exe
Message: Failed to read environment variable [DOTNET_STARTUP_HOOKS], HRESULT: 0x800700CB
```

That was enough to go on to [solve my specific issue.](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/87687)