# SSIS Failed to create task. Can't add tasks to Control Flow

Tags: ssis

So I'm trying to create an SSIS project but cannot add any tasks to the Control Flow.

When I try to drag any components from the toolbar, I get this error:

[image: Error]

Followed by:

[image]

I can't find anything online about it. What can I do to debug this?

UPDATE:

This only seems to happen once the package has been open for a short period of time. I keep having to close and reopen Visual Studio as a work-around

Comment: What version of VS are you using? What happens if you install a different version?

Comment: I had issues with 15.9.14 and had to revert  back to 15.8 to get some packages to work.

Comment: @JoeDBAHAHAHA 15.9.18...if I need to change version then I might leave it as only needed for low priority work

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248955/unable-to-start-debugging-because-the-object-invoked-has-disconnected-from-its-c